# Need help understanding the Route attributes in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'd greatly appreciate if someone could kindly explain [Route] attribute / routes.Add() method, its parts. I'm used to MVC framework / WebAPI and know that those pertain to Controllers and Actions.  For instance the classes, DTO objects have them as opposed to methods.  Thanks a bunch in advance.

Update 7/17/2013
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/service-stack

Excellent course that answers everything

Comment: Whilst some of us programmers are stuck working all the the time without a sabbatical the technology races us as fast as we can blink! I could not understand the basics of DTO and got a generic answer such as below. I found my answeres in attributerouting.net.  Hopefully anybody looking for answers could benefit from it. My question was regarding the Route attribute on top of a Class declaration.

Comment: Please see the [docs on Routing](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) if you haven't already.

Comment: Your docs are good when there is basic understanding. The following sites give a good foundation. Now I understand your doc!
1. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/19/asp-net-web-api-cors-support-and-attribute-based-routing-improvements.aspx 2. Go to attributerouting.net

Answer (score 1):

The route attributes you are referring to routes specific dtos to services based on the path in the route.  so something like  base.Routes.Add("/files", "GET,POST") would allow GET and POST requests to the /files path. So if my api lives in /api I can hit

```
http://localhost/api/files
```

with a GET or a POST and it should be routed to the correct service(s).  You can think of this like what mvc does and keep in mind that mvc WILL mess with teh routes of service stack if the path is not ignored in mvc.  In your route config of mvc make sure to put something like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute "api/{*pathInfo}"
```

assuming you installed service stack to run on the path /api (this can be found in your web.config). Also, if you are using mvc4 i would recommend taking out the webapi stuff so you dont get any conflicts with that either.